# How to navigate in different arrays and objects of a JSON file

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to get data from this JSON file like this: http://api.worldbank.org/countries/ir?format=json

If you have a look at the file by a JSON editor([like this](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org)), you will see that there are arrays and objects inside arrays. I can Only get access to the first level. But how to access to deepr levels. Here what I have done so far:

```
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");
            JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONArray array2 = array.getJSONArray(1);
            JSONObject c2 = array2.getJSONObject(0);



            //Storing JSON item in a Variable
            String name = c2.getString(NAME);
            String capitalCity = c2.getString(CAPITALCITY);
```

So by this lines of codes I can get the country name and the capital city.

But **in the same array** there is another object called **region** which it has two other strings, *id* and *value* . How can I access inside **region** and get the **value**?

Answer (score 1):

Field `region` is a `JSONObject` again:

```
JSONObject region = c2.getJSONObject("region");
String regionId = region.getString("id");
String regionValue = region.getString("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
JSONObject regionJsObj = c2.getJSONObject("region");
String regionId = regionJsObj.getString("id");
String regionValue = regionJsObj.getString("value");
```

you can do the same for all the jsonObjects that inside jsonObject as "adminregion" or "incomeLevel" or "lendingType" or so...